Single quotes in downloaded filenames using yt-dlp
I'm using the following command to download a youtube video:
yt-dlp --format 614 url_here
The resulting filename has single quotes around it and looks like:
'downloaded file name.mp4'
Anyway to not have single quotes in the filename? I'm also running this on Ubuntu.

Try adding --restrict-filenames

I did, but the single quotes were still present.

The quotes are not part of the file name; they are part of your ls output that shows the name.
Linux ls will by default display file names quoted in such a way that they can be directly copy-pasted back into Bash as part of a command. Use ls -N to disable this.

I see that now. Also, I was thinking I had to use the single quotes to operate on the file, which isn't the case. A bit of an oversight on my part I guess. All good now.
